# Wanting to specify a bit of work for a specific thread

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

In a Java test (it's actually a groovy / grails test using Java Threading), I want do something like this, in pseudo code

```
do / check work for user 1 on thread 1
do / check work for user 2 on thread 2
do / check work for user 1 on thread 1
do / check work for user 2 on thread 2
do / check work for user 1 on thread 1
```

So specific work for a specific thread.  I notice with the Execturors, you just submit to a pool so you can't specify which thread to use.  But I need to specify the thread, as I want to check a certain condition is thread safe.

I was thinking of just creating two threads and then putting the work in Callables, then in Futures and putting the Futures into the the specific threads or creating two ExcutorsService with threadpool size of 1.

Any tips or better ideas?

Comment: What condition do you need to test? Do you want some variable to be confined to one thread? In which case using a ThreadLocal would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Do you just want to execute different threads or are you trying to pass a parameter to the threads when they are executed?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a ThreadFactory to the Executor where the ThreadFactory could create the Threads for you based on the Runnable they get.